# Windows 7 logoff script?

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, vbscript

I've been trying this for a while, to no avail. I read many docs, including:
[Windows 7 - How to run a script at shutdown but not at logoff](https://superuser.com/questions/576528/windows-7-how-to-run-a-script-at-shutdown-but-not-at-logoff)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770300.aspx
http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-run-a-script-or-command-at-logoff-in-windows-7-8

I have a VBS script that works just fine when I double click it but never automatically when configured as a logoff script. I tried the script path, I tried cscript and wscript and it didn't work. What am I missing, you think?

Answer (score -1):

So note little of a user's standard things. Most paths are different. Network serverly limited. No network drives.

You should post your script.

From Help in Local Security Policy

> **Assign Computer Shutdown Scripts**
>   To assign computer shutdown scripts
>
> ...
>
> Additional considerations
>
> To complete this procedure, you must have Edit setting permission to edit a GPO. By default, members of the Domain Administrators security group, the Enterprise Administrators security group, or the Group Policy Creator Owners security group have Edit setting permission to edit a GPO.
>
> **Shutdown scripts are run as Local System**, and they have the full rights that are associated with being able to run as Local System.
>
> Setting shutdown scripts to run synchronously may cause the shutdown process to run slowly.
>
> Additional references
>
> Use Startup, Shutdown, Logon, and Logoff Scripts

From Windows SDK

> **LocalSystem Account**
>
> The LocalSystem account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the LookupAccountName function. It has extensive privileges on the local computer, and acts as the computer on the network. Its token includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs; these accounts have access to most system objects. The name of the account in all locales is .\LocalSystem. The name, LocalSystem or ComputerName\LocalSystem can also be used. This account does not have a password. If you specify the LocalSystem account in a call to the CreateService function, any password information you provide is ignored.
>
> A service that runs in the context of the LocalSystem account inherits the security context of the SCM. The user SID is created from the SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID value. The account is not associated with any logged-on user account. This has several implications:
>
> The registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER is associated with the default user, not the current user. To access another user's profile, impersonate the user, then access HKEY_CURRENT_USER.
>
> The service can open the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY.
>
> The service presents the computer's credentials to remote servers.
>
> If the service opens a command window and runs a batch file, the user could hit CTRL+C to terminate the batch file and gain access to a command window with **LocalSystem permissions.**
>
> The LocalSystem account has the following privileges:

```
SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME
SE_AUDIT_NAME
SE_BACKUP_NAME
SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME
SE_CREATE_PAGEFILE_NAME
SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_NAME
SE_CREATE_TOKEN_NAME
SE_DEBUG_NAME
SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_NAME
SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME
SE_LOAD_DRIVER_NAME
SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME
SE_PROF_SINGLE_PROCESS_NAME
SE_RESTORE_NAME
SE_SECURITY_NAME
SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME
SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
SE_SYSTEM_PROFILE_NAME
SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME
SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME
SE_TCB_NAME
SE_UNDOCK_NAME
```

> Most services do not need such a high privilege level. If your service does not need these privileges, and it is not an interactive service, consider using the LocalService account or the NetworkService account. For more information, see Service Security and Access Rights.
>
> Windows NT:  **The service has limited access to network resources, such as shares and pipes, because it has no credentials and must connect using a null session**. The following registry key contains the NullSessionPipes and NullSessionShares values, which are used to specify the pipes and shares to which null sessions may connect:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM
     CurrentControlSet
          Services
               LanmanServer
                    Parameters
```

> Alternatively, you could add the RestrictNullSessAccess value to the key and set it to 0 to allow all null sessions to access all pipes and shares created on that computer.
>
> Send comments about this topic to Microsoft
>
> Build date: 10/2/2006